# Slice list with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

I have a list, lets say:

```
list = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
```

I have some data, that returns with an Numpy array of either:

```
array([0])
array([1])
array([2])
```

Which are indicating the index of the corresponding list index.

But how can I get the array to print the list indication?

What I would like at the end result:

```
array_result = array([1])

print(f'Result  : {array_result[list]}')
Result : A2
```

So basically slice a list with an array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simple boolean indexing on both the arrays -

```
import numpy as np
l = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'] #recommend not using 'list' as variable name

array_result = np.array([0])
l[array_result[0]]
```

```
'A1'
```